Libusb Assertion Error in Car Thing Firmware Flashing
I have been attempting to flash new firmware onto my Spotify Car Thing on Windows 11, but I have been getting an error from libusb that I cannot get around. I am using the following guide and have gone through all the steps until firmware flashing with success. When attempting to flash the firmware, I get the following error:
File "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb0.py", line 528, in get_configuration assert ret == 1 AssertionError
I don't know if this is an error specific to this use case, but since it's in libusb and not the superbird tool I figured I could cast a wider net instead of just the community discord for Car Thing firmwares.
I have restarted my PC, run command prompt as admin, moved the firmware into the same folder as the superbird tool, unplugged and re-plugged in the Car Thing, used different USB ports on my PC, and tried installing WinUSB and libusb drivers on the Car Thing. I also tried to see what would happen if I commented out or changed the assertion value in libusb0.py but obviously that didn't work.
